# Adding new Object inside Json at the front

Tags: json, angularjs

I am having a json object Like this

```
[{"SubLoc":"a","Description":"A","Equipment":""},{"SubLoc":"b","Description":"B","Equipment":""},{"SubLoc":"c","Description":"C","Equipment":""},{"SubLoc":"d","Description":"D","Equipment":""}]
```

I want to add one more attribute in front so that the JSON will look like

```
[{"SubLoc":"Select","Description":"Select","Equipment":""},{"SubLoc":"a","Description":"A","Equipment":""},{"SubLoc":"b","Description":"B","Equipment":""},{"SubLoc":"c","Description":"C","Equipment":""},{"SubLoc":"d","Description":"D","Equipment":""}]
```

i tried unshift like this-

```
$scope.JsonVar.unshift({SubLoc:'Select', Description:'Select'});
```

but its giving me result like this...

```
[{"SubLoc":"Select","Description":"Select","Equipment":""}[{"SubLoc":"a","Description":"A","Equipment":""},{"SubLoc":"b","Description":"B","Equipment":""},{"SubLoc":"c","Description":"C","Equipment":""},{"SubLoc":"d","Description":"D","Equipment":""}]]
```

Comment: Your result is not even valid JSON, and there is a superficial `.` in your call to `unshift`. Please make sure you fix all the typos in your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`unshift()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp) method returns the new length of the array, and not the array itself. So you must not reassign your result to `$scope.JsonVar`. Just use it like this:

```
$scope.JsonVar.unshift({SubLoc:'Select', Description:'Select'});
```

Comment: Check this [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/hobimefixa/1/edit?html,js,output), the code I posted definitely works. Reproduce your problem in a JSBin or similar and add it to your question.